# Can't install Laravel nova custom field's npm dependencies

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, npm, laravel-nova

When I started to develop some custom field for Laravel Nova, I generated the files in the nova-components folder, but when I wanted to install `npm` dependencies, I got an error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/pafi/nova-components/Json/node_modules/pngquant-bin
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node lib/install.js
npm ERR! ⚠ The `/var/www/pafi/nova-components/Json/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
npm ERR!   ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
npm ERR!   ℹ compiling from source
npm ERR!   ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
npm ERR!   ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
npm ERR!     at /var/www/pafi/nova-components/Json/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pinasen/.npm/_logs/2021-06-22T14_23_05_831Z-debug.log
```

When I wanted to install the `libpng-dev` package, I got another error:

```
$ sudo apt install libpng-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng-dev : Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I can't create custom fields.

Laravel --> **8.48.0**

Laravel Nova --> **3.23.1**

Ubuntu --> **20.04.2 LTS**

Comment: did you install node in your machine.

Comment: Yes, I perfectly run a few Laravel projects with Laravel mix on the same server.